# How to print a random array in swift 2?

Tags: swift2, swift-playground

If i have a array like

```
var array = ["heads", "tails"]
```

How can i print or display a random? Like sometimes heads or tails?

I'm a beginner currently.

Language - Swift 2

Answer (score 2):

There are two options that may be used with the IBM Sandbox...

```
import SwiftShims
var array = ["heads", "tails"]
for _ in 0..<10 {
    print(array[Int(_swift_stdlib_arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count))])
}
```

or

```
import Glibc
var array = ["heads", "tails"]
for _ in 0..<10 {
   print(array[Int(random() % array.count)])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to generate a random `Int` between `0` and `array length - 1`.

Then use that number to access the array.

```
let list = ["heads", "tails"]
assert(!list.isEmpty)
let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(list.count)))
print(list[random])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the random function which returns a random `Int`:

```
import Foundation

// returns randomly 0 or 1
random() % 2

// returns randomly had or tails
array[random() % 2]
```

Unfortunately online Swift compilers don't support `random()` therefore we have to implement a random generator ourselves (from the [Swift Book](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)):

```
// random generator
final class LinearCongruentialGenerator {
    var lastRandom = 42.0
    let m = 139968.0
    let a = 3877.0
    let c = 29573.0

    func random() -> Double {
        lastRandom = ((lastRandom * a + c) % m)
        return lastRandom / m
    }
}

let r = LinearCongruentialGenerator()

var array = ["heads", "tails"]
for _ in 0..<100 {
    print(array[Int(r.random() * 2)])
}
```

Here the [IBM Swift Sandbox](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/314f499b368e9f63af29938cddb35269af40231c36b857c2cf25261a803e63fa)

Comment: It's not printing anything.

Comment: @user5895179 You have to use print: `print(array[random() % 2])`

Comment: Tried. Giving a error. I'm using swift online compiler.

Comment: @user5895179 Edited answer to be compatible with online Swift compilers.

Comment: Thanks!! The previous one was compatible with xcode?

Comment: random on IBM Sandbox is available when import Glibc . see my answer, how to use even arc4random_uniform there ...

Answer (score 0):

For a more generic solution, make an extension to `array` that returns a random element (or `nil` if the array is empty)

```
extension Array {
    func getRandomElement() -> Element? {
        if self.count > 0 {
            return self[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count) ?? 0))]
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

var arr = ["heads", "tails"]
print(arr.getRandomElement() ?? "Array empty...") // "tails", ...
```

Or, using a non-generic condensed solution

```
print(arr[Int(arc4random_uniform(2))])
```

The method `arc4random_uniform(n)` returns a random integer in the span `0..<n`, and is, in this case, preferable over using `random()` followed by a modulo operation; `random()` returns *any* integer representable by `Int`.

---

(I now noted that you mentioned in the comments to Qbyte:s answer that your are using an online compiler which seemingly doesn't support e.g. `arc4random_uniform`. See @user3441734:s answer for how to access e.g. the `arc4random_uniform` method for a such a case)

Comment: dfri,  you can still use arc4random_uniform on Linux platform (IBM Sandbox). see my answer, how to do it ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
var array = ["heads", "tails"]
```

Suppose

```
var range = 100
random() % range  // It Returns int
```

It will return a random number between 0 and 100

```
rand() % 2 // It Returns Int32

array[rand()%2]  //Error
array[random()%2]  //Random
```